# My login script is not tallying the data from MongoDb for already registered users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, express, backend

I have created a register and login script in nodejs to send and save my data to MongoDB when user registers he must be allowed to login with any one of the registered emails but my login does not work that way please here is my code:

```
const User = require("./models/user");
const Worker = require("./models/worker");
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  
      // Check if the email is already registered
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (existingUser) {
        console.log("Email already registered:", email); // Debugging statement
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already registered" });
      }
  
      // Create a new user
      const newUser = new User({ username, email, password });
  
      // Generate and store the verification token
      newUser.verificationToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
  
      // Save the user to the database
      await newUser.save();
  
      // Debugging statement to verify data
      console.log("New User Registered:", newUser);
  
      // Send verification email to the user
      // Use your preferred email service or library to send the email
      sendVerificationEmail(newUser.email, newUser.verificationToken);
  
      res.status(201).json({
        message:
          "Registration successful. Please check your email for verification.",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error during registration:", error); // Debugging statement
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Registration failed" });
    }
  });

  const generateSecretKey = () => {
    const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
  
    return secretKey;
  };
  
  const secretKey = generateSecretKey();
  
  //endpoint to login the user!
  app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;
  
      //check if the user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid email or password" });
      }
  
      //check if the password is correct
      if (user.password !== password) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid password" });
      }
  
      //generate a token
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secretKey);
  
      res.status(200).json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Login Failed" });
    }
  });
```

Now in my login screen frontend part:

```
const handleLogin = async ()  => {
    // Check if the entered email and password match the user details from the UserProvider
    const user = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user),
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        Alert.alert("Success Login");
        navigation.navigate("Home"); // Navigate to Home page after successful login
      } else {
        setButtonBgColor("#FF0000");
        Alert.alert("Login Error", "Invalid Email or Password");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // Handle network or other errors here
    }
  };
```

It my first time connecting to the backend for a react app please help me fix it

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Ignoring the fact you seems to be storing plain-text password, does the new user get added to mongodb when they register? If it does, are all the properties you expect to be populated actually populated? Does the email work from `sendVerificationEmail`?  What response are you getting from `const response = await fetch(...);`?

Comment: @jQueeny yes the registrations are showing in MongoDB and with all properties. The login is not working like it should. The login must check if the email is already in the database and let the user log in with its password but it is saying Invalid Email instaed

Comment: So just to be clear, your `const user = await User.findOne({ email });` is not returning a match? If so, can you `console.log(user)` directly after you call it? Is it `null`?

Comment: @jQueeny it gives me the Alert:`Invalid Email or Password` and my console outputs the complete document that was inserted at registration with username, email, password etc

Comment: In your `app.post("/login` route can you `console.log(req.body)` to see if the `email` key and value pair is actually being sent correctly by your `fetch` request.

Comment: yes it is sending correctly `{ email: 'xxxxx@gmail.com', password: 'xxxxxxx' }`

Comment: Something doesn't sound right. If, your `const user = await User.findOne({ email });` returned a document then your `if (!user)` statement would be false and it certainly wouldn't return `res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid email or password" });` becuase it is now outside of the control flow.

Comment: @jQueeny the Invalid alert is coming from the frontend code I shared above in the if/else block

Comment: Ok, so you need to see what the error returned from `fetch` was, not your custom `Alert.alert` in the `else` block. The `response.ok` will only be true  if the response has status 200-299. Clearly it's not. In your `else` block do `const text = await response.text(); console.log(text); console.log(response.status);`

Comment: yes I am getting status 500 which is not OK

Comment: OK good. So all you have to do is `const json = await response.json(); console.log(json);` do this before the `if (response.ok` statement.

Comment: Same, json string shows 500 status code response : ok : false